# How to update spark dataframe based on ID column row by row(OR window by window)

Tags: apache-spark, foreach, apache-spark-sql, sql-update

I have a DF with columns: `TXN_ID, SMO_ID, FLAG`
Values are:

```
12,340,null
12,56,null
12,353,null
13,340,null
13,56,null
13,353,null
```

Ask is:
To arrange the DF in ascending order of `TXN_ID`.
Then update transaction id wise and not all the rows in one go.

1st update:
set col `FLAG` as '`Y`' against the min value of `SMO_ID`(String column, so lexically ordered, i.e. 340 will be the smallest here) where FLAG is null or already 'Y'

then 2nd:
Update all the other rows in complete DF and set `FLAG='N'`, against the `SMO_ID` which got updated as 'Y' in above step

The scenario is tricky as the update needs to be done transaction_id wise and the second update depends on the value from first update.

I tried with using forloop, foreach with withColumn but these are not the working options.
Also, spark sql does not support update operation.

Is there any way to achieve this stateful update.

Output would look like: Taking TXN_ID=12 as example as it should be updated first in asc order.[here rows with TXN_ID=12 are in scope]

1st part of update would look like

```
12,340,Y
12,353,null
12,56,null
```

Now, for other occurrences of SMO_ID=340 in the rows ahead, FLAG should be set as N.[here complete DF is in scope]

```
12,340,Y
12,353,null
12,56,null
13,340,N
13,56,null
13,353,null
```

Similarly, it should continue for TXN_ID=13...

Comment: I don't get it.

Can you share an expected output? As for my understanding, there should be two rows with flags = 'Y' (the ones with SMO_ID = 340) the other ones should be N?

Answer (score 0):

Min value can be evaluated, then rownum assigned to each row in natural order, and rows related to min value changed:

```
val df = Seq(
  (12, "340", null.asInstanceOf[String]),
  (12, "56", null.asInstanceOf[String]),
  (12, "353", null.asInstanceOf[String]),
  (13, "340", null.asInstanceOf[String]),
  (13, "56", null.asInstanceOf[String]),
  (13, "353", null.asInstanceOf[String])
).toDF("TXN_ID", "SMO_ID", "FLAG")

val minValue = df.select(min($"SMO_ID")).as(Encoders.STRING).first()
val smoIdWindow = Window.partitionBy("SMO_ID").orderBy("naturalOrder")
df
  .withColumn("naturalOrder", monotonically_increasing_id())
  .withColumn("rownum", row_number().over(smoIdWindow))
  .withColumn("FLAG",
    when($"SMO_ID" === lit(minValue),
      when($"rownum" === 1, "Y").otherwise("N")
    ).otherwise($"FLAG")
  )
  .drop("naturalOrder","rownum")
```

Output:

```
+------+------+----+
|TXN_ID|SMO_ID|FLAG|
+------+------+----+
|12    |353   |null|
|13    |353   |null|
|12    |340   |Y   |
|13    |340   |N   |
|12    |56    |null|
|13    |56    |null|
+------+------+----+
```